# Change content iframe youtube

Tags: jquery, iframe

I want to hide right menu of youtube player with jQuery

```
$('iframe').contents().find
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/812hzbkd/) 
but it doesn't work

How to change `<ul class="html5-context-menu yt-uix-button-menu"`  with `style z-index:10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access cross domain origin iframe content. Browsers will block direct access like this: http://screencast.com/t/PIJj3iARU1z